# Running Windows Powershell from PHP unaware of Current Profile

Tags: php, windows, powershell, command-line

I have a few functions and variables defined for all machine users like so:

```
Set-Content $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost (Get-Content path/to/myprofile.ps1)
```

Let's call one of my defined functions `Do-Stuff`.
This works very well. And anytime Powershell console is called up, and you type "Do-Stuff"+ENTER, it works.

Now I have tried to call this function from PHP a few ways, and I'm having a couple of problems. Consider this:

```
$res = shell_exec( 'Powershell Do-Stuff');
print_r($res);
```

What I get is this error:

```
Do-Stuff: The term 'Do-Stuff' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....
```

I've tried also:

```
$res = shell_exec( 'Powershell -File path/to/script.ps1');
print_r($res);
```

If the file `script.ps1` does contain `Do-Stuff` or any of the other defined functions, what I get is the same type of error message.

Now what this tells me is that the calling PHP script is NOT recognized as a Windows machine user, and the currently loaded `$Profile` is NOT being applied.

So what's the solution to this? How can I get the loaded profile for current user or all users to be applied to the running PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this issue, using `-NoProfile`, then dot-sourcing the Profile file.

In the below example, the profile file is `includes.ps1`:

```
$cmdlet = 'Do-Stuff';
$cmd = 'Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -NoProfile -Command "& { . \includes.ps1; '.$cmdlet.' }"';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

It may prove useful for you to enclose this in a reusable function:

```
<?php
function run_ps_command($cmdlet, $async=true){  
    $cmd = 'Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -NoProfile -Command "& { . \Includes.ps1; '.$cmdlet.' }"';
    if($async){
        $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
        $res = $WshShell->Run( $cmd, 0, false);
    }else{
        $res = shell_exec($cmd);
    }
    return $res;
}
?>
```

The `$async` argument allows you to run this command without having PHP wait for the output of the PowerShell script. The advantage is that PHP code execution is faster, the disadvantage is: you've no idea if your script ran successfully, or got into any trouble on the way ;)